# mysql MyISAM database and foreign-key-relationship worked in phpmyadmin, how? was there an update with the MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-key-relationship, myisam

I have a mysql database with 21 tables, all have relationships setup, I made them in phpMyAdmin with the designer. I'm confused as MyISAM does not support relations. Unless there was an update I can't find.

Was there an update that makes MyISAM now work with relationships?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is correct, so it will be 'accepted'. You don't get any SQL errors.

The key won't be added. (verify this by exporting your db: you will not see the key)

Comment: humm. `
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CONFIG` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SITE_NAME` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `AUTHOR` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `DESCRIPTION` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `KEYWORDS` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
`

Comment: I presume that is the export? So you see, there is no key. So the situations is that any  ADD FOREIGN KEY commands work, but don't do anything. And yes, change to innodb should work :)

Comment: phpmyadmin must have its own database storing these keys as they still show in its designer..

Comment: @Nanne the change to innodb worked on every table but how do i view the links? in phpmyadmin it is using designer for internal links i dont think they are in the innodb :| any ideas?

Comment: Below the rows in "structure" view you should see a "Relation View" link. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: there are no relations in the table, goto http://typewith.me/bRC8cdoXzc for live chat..

Comment: @Nannie they are, relationships not foreign keys, how do i change it?

Comment: sry, no time/place for chat now :). AFAIK, a foreign key is a relationship

Comment: Not in this case. the relations are set in the designer tab but not set under the innodb relations.

Comment: im now using mysql workbench to do this as ite heaps cleaner than the designer.